# Databinding example with Dart polymer - why is it different

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am going through this example at https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/example/core_selection.html

The code is Dart.

Yet looking at the databinding

```dart
selectAction(e, detail) {
   detail['item'].classes.toggle('selected', detail['isSelected']);
}
```

the method definition is not the same as what I expected

```dart
selectAction(e, detail, element) {
   detail['item'].classes.toggle('selected', detail['isSelected']);
}
```

Why the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until a while ago Polymer.dart required that event handler methods have these three arguments but this is not required anymore.

The event handler method can accepts 0 - 3 arguments.

In the above example `target` or like you named it `element` is not passed as argument. This argument is somewhat redundant because you get access the same value by `e.target` (the same for `detail`/`e.detail`)

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I wish the polymer.dart team would give us some where that we could find changes when they are made. It would save us a lot of time. I am using polymer 0.11.0+5, from what version of polymer has these changes be made?

Comment: I don't know when this was changed. Recently in a comment to another question @Robert mentioned it.

Comment: While the e.target works, the d.detail does NOT. The event handler, as you stated will also accept 1-3 arguments.